# Replace a value in a nested array

Tags: list-manipulation

When I run the following,

```
red = {{{-4, 50}, {100, 136}}, {{-19, 1}, {35, 73}}, {{-24, 0}, {26, 63}}}; 
y = {{0.01497, 1}, {0.04304, 3}, {0.07111, 2}, {0.09918, 1}}; 
red=Interval@@@red;
If[#[[1]] <= 0.05, xii = #[[2]]; If[IntervalMemberQ[red[[xii]], 47], #[[1]] = 999.];] & /@ y;
y
```

Instead of the following result

```
y = {{999., 1}, {999., 3}, {0.07111, 2}, {0.09918, 1}}
```

I am getting an error:

```
 Set::setps:{0.01497`,1} in the part assignment is not a symbol. >>
```

I know based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12879534/2429050) that it is to do with passing name of the variable vs. value of the variable, but not sure how to fix it. I tried `Insert[#, 999., 1]` and `ReplaceList[#, 1 -> 999.]` without much success :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming I follow what you are doing I believe this may be the simplest correction:

```
red = {{{-4, 50}, {100, 136}}, {{-19, 1}, {35, 73}}, {{-24, 0}, {26, 63}}};
y = {{0.01497, 1}, {0.04304, 3}, {0.07111, 2}, {0.09918, 1}};
red = Interval @@@ red;

Do[
 If[
   y[[i, 1]] <= 0.05,
   xii = y[[i, 2]]; If[IntervalMemberQ[red[[xii]], 47], y[[i, 1]] = 999.];
 ],
 {i, Length@y}
]

y
```

> ```
> {{999., 1}, {999., 3}, {0.07111, 2}, {0.09918, 1}}
> ```

However you may find that in-place modification of `y` is not beneficial; in that case consider something like this:

```
y = {{0.01497, 1}, {0.04304, 3}, {0.07111, 2}, {0.09918, 1}};

fn[{a_, b_}] /; a <= 0.05 && IntervalMemberQ[red[[b]], 47] := {999., b}

fn[else_] := else

fn /@ y
```

> ```
> {{999., 1}, {999., 3}, {0.07111, 2}, {0.09918, 1}}
> ```

Comment: Pattern matching approach based 100% on @Mr.Wizard's answer: `y /. {a_, b_} /; a <= 0.05 && IntervalMemberQ[red[[b]], 47] :> {999., b}`

Comment: @seismatica Very nice.  Consider using `Replace` with a *levelspec* of `{1}` for optimum performance.  In writing the answer above I was thinking about a function that could be mapped but freed from that I prefer your approach. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Have to admit I'm rather spoilt by all the short notations of MMA that I'd just feel too lazy to use `Replace` with all those extra characters :p

Comment: @seismatica It sounds like I have a disciple in the School of Terse! :D

Answer (score 2):

**Attempt from question : Mutable and immutable approach mixed up (not working)**

As Mr.Wizard pointed out, there is a mutable approach and an immutable approach. In the first case you modify y directly. In the second case the program returns a whole new vector, and you assign y the value of this vector.

In the question you mix the two approaches, because you use `map[]`, which returns an expression, and at the same time you try to modify y directly. However, something goes wrong when you try to modify y.

`#[[1]]` refers to the value of y[[1]] and not to the variable y[[y]]

**Mutable and immutable approach mixed up (working)**

If you want to use a map (like you did with /@), than use `MapIndexed`.

Try `MapIndexed[f, {a, b, c}]` to understand how it works

```
{f[a, {1}], f[b, {2}], f[x, {3}]}
```

Now you can refere to `y[[#2[[1]]`

```
red = {{{-4, 50}, {100, 136}}, {{-19, 1}, {35, 73}}, {{-24, 0}, {26, 63}}};
y = {{0.01497, 1}, {0.04304, 3}, {0.07111, 2}, {0.09918, 1}};
red = Interval @@@ red;

MapIndexed[
If[#1[[1]] <= 0.05, xii = #1[[2]]; 
   If[IntervalMemberQ[red[[xii]], 47], y[[#2[[1]], 1]] = 999.];
]& 
, y];
```

**Mutable aproach**

Mr.Wizard used a Do loop, which does not return an expression.

**Immutable approach**

```
Map[
{ If[#[[1]] <= 0.05, 
      xii = #[[2]];
      If[IntervalMemberQ[red[[xii]], 47], 999., #[[1]]];
      , #[[1]]]
  , #[[2]]
} &
, y]
```

This returns

```
{{999., 1}, {999., 3}, {0.07111, 2}, {0.09918, 1}}
```

Comment: I voted for this because it is clean, and I like that, but the reason I chose `Do` is that using `Map` (or `MapIndexed`) builds an output expression which pretty much defeats any use of in-place modification.  IMHO either use `Scan` or `Do` for a mutable style or choose an immutable style and use `Map` etc.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks for this comment. Indeed you could rewrite this in immutable style. Now it mixes up two approaches.